# Using javascript to take snap shot but the code below i want to save it to database

Tags: javascript, php, html

Below is a complete code to use java script to take a snap shot from your webcam but am having issues on how to save it to database.Please i need help on how to save it to db. am using a mysql database i just want the image captured to be store in the database.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Display Webcam Stream</title>

<style>
#container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    border: 10px #333 solid;
}
#videoElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;
    background-color: #666;
}
#canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 375px;

    background-color: #CCC;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<!-- On iOS 6 we can use the file select input with the following attributes to capture an image from the camera -->
<input id="fileselect" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">





<!-- Used to capture frame from webcam video feed -->
<input name="fff" type="button" id="save" value="Save" />

<-- Or alternatively added to an img tag -->

<img id="imgtag" src="" width="500" height="375" alt="capture" />'



<?php
 include 'conn.php';
if(isset($_POST['Ponti']))
{
     $abc = "<script>document.getElementByID('uri').value</script>";
echo $abc;

 $image = new Imagick($abc);
$data = $image->getImageBlob();
$data = $mysqli->real_escape_string($data);


}
mysql_close(); 


 ?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="submit" name="Ponti" id="Ponti" value="Next" />
</form>

<-- For the JavaScript below -->
<script>
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

// check for getUserMedia support
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {      
    // get webcam feed if available
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
}

function handleVideo(stream) {
    // if found attach feed to video element
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}

function videoError(e) {
    // no webcam found - do something
}
var v,canvas,context,w,h;
var imgtag = document.getElementById('imgtag'); // get reference to img tag
var sel = document.getElementById('fileselect'); // get reference to file select input element

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    // when DOM loaded, get canvas 2D context and store width and height of element
    v = document.getElementById('videoElement');
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

},false);

function draw(v,c,w,h) {

    if(v.paused || v.ended) return false; // if no video, exit here

    context.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h); // draw video feed to canvas

   var uri = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // convert canvas to data URI

   // console.log(uri); // uncomment line to log URI for testing

   imgtag.src = uri; // add URI to IMG tag src








}

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',function(e){

    draw(v,context,w,h); // when save button is clicked, draw video feed to canvas

});

// for iOS

// create file reader
var fr;

sel.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    var f = sel.files[0]; // get selected file (camera capture)

    fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = receivedData; // add onload event

    fr.readAsDataURL(f); // get captured image as data URI
})

function receivedData() {          
    // readAsDataURL is finished - add URI to IMG tag src
    imgtag.src = fr.result;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JS code is running on the client side. So you should send AJAX request with your picture to store it in the database on a server.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using Ajax as @Slam suggests is the best solution, but if you are not familiar enough with javascript, you can also use a standard form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Take a picture:
    <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Of course, you can substitute the submit button with something else if you prefer.

You will need to implement also the php code that will receive the file and save it in the database.

As described in [file upload in php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp), you can use a code like the following:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Where:

> $target_dir = "uploads/" - specifies the directory where the file is going to be placed
>
> $target_file specifies the path of the file to be uploaded
>
> $uploadOk=1 is a variable that you can use later in your code to know if the upload was ok (if the file posted was an image as expected)
>
> $imageFileType holds the file extension of the file

This example is not completed. Please refer to the linked article. The article does not describe how to save the image in mysql. You will need to study how to do it on a book or on Internet.

Comment: thanks it worked but is there a way i can resize the image to reduce d size before i upload it to the folder and secondly how can i display the image on the page before it is taken to upload.php